# Expressjs - Get req.route in a middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm trying to get req.route in an expressjs middleware, but it seems that req.route is populated only in the router middleware.

Is there any way to run a middleware globally between the router and the actual business logic in a way as to have access to the req.route value?

Thanks!

Comment: `...; app.use(router_middleware); app.use(my_middleware); ...`?

Comment: that just tries to run the middleware like this: controller_method -> my_middleware; i need my_middleware->controller_method

Comment: Then in your controller, call `next` at the end (in the same way a middleware would do), and send the response in your middleware. Then you just need to put `app.use(my_middleware)` after your `app.get`/`app.post`

Comment: Could you post the name of your "router middleware", if it `create req.route`, any controller or middleware after it should be able to access it.

Comment: it's the express router. Also, I need to call it before my controller, not after.

Comment: Could you show your code?